Visualization for radar observation of meteor showers
This question is in continuation of the thread Radar Observation of a Meteor Shower (April-Lyrids) 
More often, the radiant of a meteor shower may be visible at a specific location only after the peak UT. And, we need the Alt/Az of the radiant within plus or minus 30 degrees to the normal to the radar. So i tried to visualize the Alt-Az of the radiant of the April Lyrids (as Green Square in the attached image) and Eta Aquariids (Green Pentagon) at the time of their peak UT w.r.t. an observer location of 10.0 N and 76.0 E. I took Eta Aquarids since it is more visible in the northern hemisphere. I would like to seek feedback from this community of experts for refining this visualization for improvisation, enhancing scientific accuracy, and clarity of thoughts. Thank you.

Initial issue... I can't tell if that green dot is high up in the East,  about 2/3 of the way from E to the zentith, or close to the horizon in the North.  The projection makes both plausible.

What does "visualization for improvisation" mean?
